# Как сделать мобильную версию сайта на битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Адаптив не предлагать. Есть задача сделать отдельную мобильную версию сайта на поддомене ( m.site.ru ) и чтобы посетитель мог с мобильной версии переходить на полную версию и обратно. Как это правильно осуществить? Я создал поддомен с названием m.site.ru и нагуглил два варианта:

1. Создал папку в корне сайта с названием "m" скопировал весь проект и даже папку "bitrix", но не htaccess, и перекинул туда (чтобы потом через htaccess корневой папки редиректить человека который зашёл , и чтобы там уже править стили и структуру сайта под мобильную версию. Но конечно возникли проблемы так как index.php направляет все подключения header, footer и тд не в папку "m" , а директорией выше то есть в корень проекта. Отсюда вопрос как сделать чтобы стили и структура HTML брались из папки "m", но чтобы например товары которые создаются для десктопной версии появлялись и в мобильной и вообще правильно ли так делать?
2. Второй вариант (это связано с type pda и php выражением) когда один шаблон, где лежит все и header и footer и тд , и лежит он в папке битрикс, просто копируешь его и переименовываешь и через php код выясняешь с какого устройств зашёл посетитель. Тут все просто если один шаблон и там идут все подключения , но у меня все разбросано по разным папкам и несколько шаблонов и лежат они в папке local/templates и ещё непонятно где. Как все это правильно организовать ? Может есть ещё какие нибудь варианты ? Подскажите правильный путь .

Comment: Если это не адаптивный сайт, а именно отдельная мобильная версия, то для неё необходимо создать другой шаблон (т.е. фактически другой сайт), что совершенно не мешает выводить туда информацию из тех же самых инфоблоков (товары), которые выводятся на десктопной версии.

Comment: Это называется __многосайтовость__ и рассматривается в битриксовых учебных курсах.

Answer (score 2):

Перекидывать весь проект это нарушение лицензионного соглашения :) а самое главное совершенно не нужное действие утяжеляющее дальнейшую поддержку. Раз уж адаптив не предлагать то отсается два варианта реализации:
 1. Непосредственно мобильная версия сайта. Битрикс позволяет использовать разные шаблоны сайтов. В админке их список доступен, и их можно дополнять. Распологаются они в специальном каталоге Точнее возможно в двух:
- /bitrix/templates/  - раньше там размещали, также туда ставятся шаблоны устанавливаемые из маркетплейса и из коробки битрикс
- /local/templates/ - рекомендуемое место размещения своих шаблонов сайтов.

Таким образом вам необходимо создать новый шаблон для мобильной версии. Как вариант скопировать текущий и доработать.

Тут стоит обратить внимание на шаблоны отдельных компонентов. Обычно они располагаются (если не стандартные шаблоны из поставки битрикс) в каталоге /путь_шаблона_сайта/components/разработчик/имя_компонента/имя_шаблона_компонента/.  Если для отдельного компонента у вас используется один общий шаблон для всех шаблонов сайта, то его стоит перенести в общий каталог
/local/templates/.default/components/разработчик/имя_компонента/имя_шаблона_компонента/  (именно перенести, а не копировать)

Далее необходимо создать функцию определяющую устройство в init.php. можно воспользоваться функцией АПИ. Вот пример.

```
function is_mobile() {
    CModule::IncludeModule("fileman");
    return CLightHTMLEditor::IsMobileDevice();
}
```

далее в Админке в настройках сайта, добавить мобильный шаблон в список шаблонов (до основного) и указать тип условия "Выражение PHP" занчение условия "is_mobile()"

2. Создать мобильное приложение. Правда на это необходима отдельная лицензия.

Но нужно учитывать, что определение мобильного устройства, по сути идет по косвенным признакам, и вполне возможна ситуация, когда устройство не определиться как мобильное. По-этому лично я рекомендую своим клиентам адаптив. (да и долгосрочная стоимость поддержки дешевле)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развёрнутый и понятный ответ !